# pycharm introducing bugs in the code by putting un-necessary space between variable names

Tags: pycharm, pep8

I'm using the Pycharm community edition (v 2021.1.1 ) for my Python project. Pycharm has this handy feature that warns you about pep-8 formattings such as spaces, blank lines before and after functions etc and it even has a feature which fixes these formatting errors by putting spaces and blank line by itself.

However, this autoformatting feature is such a big mess that it even puts spaces between variable names, creating many syntax errors. For example, there is this piece of code

```
i0 = 10
i1 = 100
U = 500
for index1 in range (0, i0-1):
   print ("do something")

for index1 in range (i1+1, U ) :
   print ("so something else")
```

In this piece of code the 'intelligent' pycharm formatting, renamed `i0` to `i 0` and `i1` to `i1`, caused the code to fail. Is there any way to avoid errors like these?
or To hide the pep8 formatting suggestions (annoying) from Pycharm?
[image: Before formatting]

[[image: after Pycharm's 'inelligent' formatting2]

Comment: As you should expect, PyCharm should not do what you are seeing, and it will bother most of programmers if it does this. So I would check settings and pug-ins. Or you associate the file with a non Python format. In short: check your settings

Comment: Hi,  Can you specify which option in settings I should check? I have not associated the file to anon-python format. Pycharm knows very well that this is a python file.

Comment: I just tested it with PyCharm 2021.1.1 and your code sample. It doesn't behave the same way for me. So possibly you have a specific config in place or a plugin that interferes. Try disabling plugins you installed yourself or resetting config defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest altering your variable names to use `snake_case`.
The advantage of this is that you're clearly delineating the 'type' of variable (e.g `fft` result) and the *instance* of that type (e.g `0` or `1`).

This should be a straightforward change in case you can't stop Pycharm's style changes, while making your code more PEP-8 compliant and more importantly, easier to read. (IMO).

See for yourself:

```
fft0 = 10
fft1 = 100
fft2 = 1000
fft3 = 10000
```

versus:

```
fft_0 = 10
fft_1 = 100
fft_2 = 1000
fft_3 = 10_000
```

It's all personal preference but I'd wager that most people would find the latter easier to parse.